# Каково происхождение выражения «скучать за тобой»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скучать по вас (П.п.), скучать по вам (Д.п.) и ещё ненормативное "скучать за тобой" (Т.п.).

А каково происхождение этой формы, использовалась ли она в русском языке, в каких диалектах сохранилась? Сам Т.п. особых вопросов не вызывает, существуют такие выражения, как *любоваться тобой, следить за тобой,* предлог ЗА входит в состав причинного предлога ИЗ-ЗА.

Вопросы о форме "скучать за тобой" задаются постоянно, значит, где-то используется это выражение.

Из форума:

> Правильно — по тебе. А "за тобой" — в некоторых русских диалектах
> тоже употребляется.
>
> Вот только нет в украинском выражения "Нудьгую по тобі." Есть - "сумую
> за тобою", а если в прошедшем времени "скУчила за тобою.

[Как правильно "скучаю по тебе" или "скучаю за тобой"? | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/38063283)

> Она, поняв, разом выпроваживает всех, сама, усадив на лавку,
> стаскивает с него дорожные сапоги, валится головою ему в колени,
> обнимая полными руками, шепчет: **«Ладо! Истомилась я за тобой!**»

(Дмитрий Балашов "Симеон Гордый")

Почему автор использует это сочетание?

Answer (score 1):

> Милый папа! Я здоров и очень скучаю за тобой. Прошу приезжай скорей.
>   Кланяйся бабушке и Саре тёте. Целую тебя и остаюсь твой сын Александр.
>   Симферополь. (Марина Спендиарова Izd-vo AN Armi︠a︡nskoĭ SSR, 1975)

Редкий случай (моё мнение), по большей же части о своих переживаниях говорят матери, жёны.

> Как уехал ты – я в крик, – бабы прибежали. «Ой, разлуки, – говорят, –
>   ей не перенесть». Так скучала за тобой, что меня держали, – хоть
>   причина не скучать очень даже есть. Тута Пашка приходил – кум твой
>   окаянный, – еле-еле не ... (Владимир Высоцкий. 2014)

И они, женщины, в части стилистически сниженной лексики — первейший источник. Действительно, в состав причинного предлога *из-за* входит проблемный предлог *за*. Хорошее наблюдение, кое-что проясняюшее. А как приставка он входит в наречие *замужем*. Это тот случай, когда при схожих глаголах «чувства» (тосковать, скучать, горевать, плакать, тужить) *замужем* может вполне замещать проблемное *за тобой*.